# How to get data from child in an array from JSON file in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this JSON file:
[Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCmVc.png)

I'm destructuring from the component and getting data from props:

```
class  CustomHeader extends Component {


    render() { 

        const { headerBackground, logo} = this.props.customdesign;
        console.log(logo.sizelogo);

    }


}
```

I have no problem when getting data from parent:

```
console.log(logo);
```

**Console gives me:** sizelogo: "12", urllogo: "http://fire.info"

but I can't get child data from **logo** in this case **sizelogo**:

```
console.log(logo.sizelogo);
```

**Console gives me:** TypeError: Cannot read property 'sizelogo' of undefined

I have try different things like:

```
class  CustomHeader extends Component {


    render() { 

        const { headerBackground, logo, logo: sizelogo} = this.props.customdesign;
        console.log(sizelogo);

    }


}
```

But just getting errors

Any idea how to get child data?

Comment: Can you add console.log for customdesign, logo and your whole props?

Comment: Are you getting this json data from a API call ? If yes, then this could be happening because the data isn't injected in props by the time you try to access `logo.sizelogo`. In this case try `logo && console.log(logo.sizelogo)`

Comment: Domino987 I can get the whole props no problem, the problem comes when trying to access to child.

Comment: makk_bit You are right 
Using: logo && console.log(logo.sizelogo) returns the correct value ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you iterate over multiple Json object. Sometimes it works because you have a `logo`  sometimes not. So either you make sur that your props is always fill or you can prevent the error.

To avoid to crash an error you can add this kind of statement (before your console logo)

`const sizeLogo = this.logo ? this.logo.sizeLogo : "no logo"`

Then

`console.log(sizeLogo)`

Comment: You are right.  As makk_bit said  "the data isn't injected in props by the time I try to access"

So in this case to make a const what is the best solution to make sure that I have the data? 

To call the JSON I was using async () and await fetch() I thought that it will prevent this problem.

Comment: I'm using: 
const sizelogo = logo && logo.sizelogo;

Is this a good practice?